# Painting to panel after .Update() call

Tags: c#, panel, paint

I have a problem when trying to draw to a panel immediatly after calling a panel.Update();
Here's the code:

```
    public void AddAndDraw(double X, double Y){
        AddPoint (X, Y);
        bool invalidated = false;

        if (X > _master.xMaxRange) {
            _master.Update ();
            invalidated = true;
        }
        if (Y > _master.yMaxRange) {
            _master.Update ();
            invalidated = true;
        }

        if (!invalidated) {
            _master.UpdateGraph (this);
        } else {
            _master.PaintContent ();
        }
    }
```

When running this problem I only see the cleared panel and not he content I'm trying to paint in the .PaintContent()-method. I've already tried using .Invalidate() and .Refresh() on the panel instead of .Update()

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't see where you draw, but it really should be __only__ in the Paint event! (__Or__ in some function called from there which __passes out the e.Graphics__ object!) - I you stick to this rule things will work. You will need to __store the drawing parameters__ somewhere! - Also note, that Update refreshes only Controls that have content that can change, like a ListBox etc.. To refresh a Panel you call panel.Invalidate().

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond.

The problem is that my panel consists of three "layers". I have subscribed a method, that draws the axis of my graph to the paint event. And then I have to separate methods to draw a whole graph, called PaintContent and one to update a single point and redraw the whole graph, if the point is beyond the ranges of either the x- or y-axis. I would like to be able to call these separately.

So far it works with the PaintContent when called from a button click, but it doesn't work in the code above. The UpdateGraph-method works fine here.

Comment: Then you need flags or some other kind of indicators of what the Paint event is supposed to draw when it is called. If you want persistent drawing this can't be avoided, unless you use Bitmaps. Try minimizing/maximizing the form and you see what  I mean! (If some parts of the drawing don't change a lot Bitmaps are maybe an option. Btw, a PictureBox has three layers: 2 Images and the control surface you can draw on.. You could paint the axes into the background image, the graph into the image and plot the single point in the paint event..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your situation calls for a `PictureBox`.

`PBs` are interesting here because they have **three** layers they can display:

- They have a `BackgroundImage` property
- They have an `Image` property
- And as most controls they have a surface you can draw on in the `Paint` event

As you need a fixed axis, and graph that is not changing all the time and a point you want to update often `PB` seems to be made for you!

Call the functions as needed and when the point has changed call `Invalidate()` on your `PictureBox`!

```
Bitmap GraphBackground = null;
Bitmap GraphImage = null;
Point aPoint = Point.Empty;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox Graph = pictureBox1;  // short reference, optional

    GraphBackground = new Bitmap(Graph.ClientSize.Width, Graph.ClientSize.Height);
    GraphImage = new Bitmap(Graph.ClientSize.Width, Graph.ClientSize.Height);

    // intial set up, repeat as needed!
    Graph.BackgroundImage = DrawBackground(GraphBackground);
    Graph.Image = DrawGraph(GraphImage);
}

Bitmap DrawBackground(Bitmap bmp)
{
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp) )
    {
        // my little axis code..
        Point c = new Point(bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2);
        G.DrawLine(Pens.DarkSlateGray, 0, c.Y, bmp.Width, c.Y);
        G.DrawLine(Pens.DarkSlateGray, c.X, 0, c.X, bmp.Height);
        G.DrawString("0", Font, Brushes.Black, c);
    }
    return bmp;
}

Bitmap DrawGraph(Bitmap bmp)
{
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        // do your drawing here

    }

    return bmp;
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // make it as fat as you like ;-)
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, aPoint.X - 3, aPoint.Y - 3, 7, 7);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, it was very useful! It seems to work fine now whit my own drawing code added.